# Codeigniter project have different result beetween hostinger and localhost

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hosting

I just upload my website from localhost to hostinger with filezilla.
I already configure the database setting and all working well, but i get different result if i want login to the website. it give error "the username or password is wrong".
After that, I run the website in my localhost. Login with same username/ password and its working.
I dont know the error, i use same code between the local and hostinger

**controller/login.php**

```
  <?php
  class Login extends CI_Controller {
   function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    session_start();
    $this->load->model(array('mlogin'));
   if ($this->session->userdata('email')) {
    $this->load->view('header1');
   }
   elseif (!$this->session->userdata('email')) {
    $this->load->view('header'); 
     }
     }
    function index() {
    $this->load->view('login');
    }

function proses() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {

        $usr = $this->input->post('email');
        $psw = $this->input->post('password');
        $u = mysql_real_escape_string($usr);
        $p = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($psw));
        $cek = $this->mlogin->cek($u, $p);
        if ($cek->num_rows() > 0) {
            //login berhasil, buat session
            foreach ($cek->result() as $qad) {
                $sess_data['u_id'] = $qad->u_id;
                $sess_data['nama'] = $qad->nama;
                $sess_data['email'] = $qad->email;
                $sess_data['role'] = $qad->role;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }
            redirect('home');
        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('result_login', '<br>Username atau Password yang anda masukkan salah.');
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}

function logout() {
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login');
}}
```

model/mlogin.php

```
 <?php

 class Mlogin extends CI_Model {

private $table = "user";

function cek($email, $password) {
    $this->db->where("email", $email);
    $this->db->where("u_paswd", $password);
    return $this->db->get("user");
}

function semua() {
    return $this->db->get("user");
}

function cekKode($kode) {
    $this->db->where("email", $kode);
    return $this->db->get("user");
}

function cekId($kode) {
    $this->db->where("u_id", $kode);
    return $this->db->get("user");
}

function getLoginData($usr, $psw) {
    $u = mysql_real_escape_string($usr);
    $p = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($psw));
    $q_cek_login = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $u, 'password' => $p));
    if (count($q_cek_login->result()) > 0) {
        foreach ($q_cek_login->result() as $qck) {
            foreach ($q_cek_login->result() as $qad) {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'vera';
                $sess_data['u_id'] = $qad->u_id;
                $sess_data['email'] = $qad->email;
                $sess_data['nama'] = $qad->nama;
                $sess_data['group'] = $qad->group;
                $sess_data['rid'] = $qad->rid;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }
            redirect('main');
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('result_login', '<br>Username atau Password yang anda masukkan salah.');
        header('location:' . base_url() . 'login');
    }
}

function update($id, $info) {
    $this->db->where("u_id", $id);
    $this->db->update("user", $info);
}

function simpan($info) {
    $this->db->insert("user", $info);
}

function hapus($kode) {
    $this->db->where("u_id", $kode);
    $this->db->delete("user");
}

 }
```

view/login.php

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log in</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">  
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">        
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet"> 

</head>
<body>
   <body class="login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="login-logo">
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form action="<?php echo site_url('login/proses'); ?>" method="post">
                <?php
                if (validation_errors() || $this->session->flashdata('result_login')) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong>Warning!</strong>
                        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('result_login'); ?>
                    </div>    
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
               </div>
               <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Masuk</button>
              <br>
             <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user"><h4>Daftar Anggota Baru</h4></a>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            </form>               
        </div><!-- /.login-box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.login-box -->

    <!-- jQuery 2.1.3 -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.3.min.js'); ?>"></script> 
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script> 
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js'); ?>"></script>       
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('input').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
                increaseArea: '20%' // optional
            });
        });
    </script>
 <script>
 $(function () {
  $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500,
    namespace: "callbacks",
    pager: true,
  });
});
</script>

  <!--footer-starts-->
  <?php $this->load->view('footer') ?>
   <!---->
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

localhost php version 5.6.11

hostinger php version 5.6.18

Comment: In this case you need to debug your code uploaded on live site. Just open a file where you made query to get record from database for provided login details. Echo query and checked it in live database. If you got row, means query and login details are fine else change login details and try again.

Comment: If you autoload session library you don't need to use this     `session_start();`

Comment: Still cannot. Help me @wolfgang1983

Comment: The code and database connection are checking the data in the database - your username and password.  You mentioned you uploaded the files, and configured a DB connection, but how about the data?  If you transferred it, how did you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostinger sensitive with capitalization

change this code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
```

with this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
```

and i think this code will give you 0 for $p

```
$p = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($psw));
```

just use this

```
$p = md5($psw);
```